# Delivering data between instances of different classes in tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

Beginner to tkinder and the version of python is 3.6.

I'm trying to make a python GUI for data processing.

There're several instances of different classes designed for different jobs.

When the data is processed with function click_emd in EMDFrame class, it should be drawn in PreviewFrame class which uses matplotlib to show the data. However i have no idea how to pass the data between two classes.

I've searched similar questions but they didn't work.

Now I'm thinking about two possible solutions.

One is to find a way to pass data_processed to previewframe.cplot in emdframe.click_emd.

Another is to make full use MainPage class. It can acquire data_processed from one class and call the cplot in another class to drawn. But how can MainPage get noticed once the data_processed is generated?

Got confused and don't know what to do. Really appreciate for your patience.

There are two py code file.

Mainframe.py :

```
import tkinter as tk
from view import *  # initiate the subframes

class MainPage():
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        self.root = master
        root.geometry('%dx%d' % (800, 600))
        self.createPage()

    def createPage(self):
        self.emdPage = EMDFrame(root)  # subframe
        self.emdPage.place(x=20, y=300)
        self.preview = PreviewFrame(root)
        self.preview.place(x=340, y=20)
        self.aboutPage = AboutFrame(root)

        menubar = Menu(root)
        menubar.add_command(label='EMD', command=self.emd)
        menubar.add_command(label='About', command=self.aboutDisp)
        root['menu'] = menubar  # set menu

    def emd(self):
        self.emdPage.place(x=20, y=300)
        self.preview.place(x=340, y=20)
        self.aboutPage.place_forget()

    def aboutDisp(self):
        self.emdPage.place_forget()
        self.preview.place_forget()
        self.aboutPage.place(x=20, y=300)

    def plot_update(self, data, t):
        self.preview.cplot(data, t)

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Demo")
app = MainPage(root)
root.mainloop()
```

view.py :

```
from tkinter import *
from pyhht.emd import EMD
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
import numpy as np

data = []

class EMDFrame(LabelFrame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        LabelFrame.__init__(self, master, width=300, height=250, text='EMD')
        self.root = master
        self.createPage()

    def createPage(self):
        b = Button(self, text='EMD', width=20, height=2, command=self.click_emd)
        b.place(x=40, y=160, anchor='nw', width=80, height=40)

    def click_emd(self):
        global data
        decomposer = EMD(data)
        data_processed = decomposer.decompose()
        # Deliever data_processed to PreviewFrame's cplot function

class PreviewFrame(LabelFrame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        LabelFrame.__init__(self, master, width=440, height=530, text='Preview')
        self.root = master
        self.createPage()

    def cplot(self, data, t):
        f = Figure(figsize=(4, 4.8), dpi=100)
        a = f.add_subplot(111)
        a.plot(t, data)

        canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(f, master=self)
        canvas.draw()
        canvas.get_tk_widget().place(x=20, y=0)


    def createPage(self):
        t = np.arange(0.0, 3, 0.01)
        s = np.sin(2 * np.pi * t)
        self.cplot(s,t)

class AboutFrame(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.root = master
        self.createPage()

    def createPage(self):
        Label(self, text='About').pack()
```

Answer (score 0):

You aren't passing data between classes, you are passing data between two instances of classes.

In order for one instance to send data to another instance of a class, it needs to know about it. So in MainFrame.py we pass the reference of the preview class to the emdPage.

```
def createPage(self):
    self.preview = PreviewFrame(root)
    self.preview.place(x=340, y=20)
    self.emdPage = EMDFrame(root,self.preview)  # subframe
    self.emdPage.place(x=20, y=300)
    self.aboutPage = AboutFrame(root)
```

Then in the other view.py, update the class to keep track of the preview reference and then use it once the data has been processed.

```
class EMDFrame(LabelFrame):
    def __init__(self, preview, master=None):
        LabelFrame.__init__(self, master, width=300, height=250, text='EMD')
        self.preview = preview
        self.root = master
        self.createPage()

    def createPage(self):
        b = Button(self, text='EMD', width=20, height=2, command=self.click_emd)
        b.place(x=40, y=160, anchor='nw', width=80, height=40)

    def click_emd(self):
        global data
        decomposer = EMD(data)
        data_processed = decomposer.decompose()
        # Deliever data_processed to PreviewFrame's cplot function
        self.preview.cplot(.....)
```

(Code example is untested and incomplete but should show the principle)
(There is probably a better way to do it thought the MainPage class but this would involve a bit more code.)

Comment: Thank you for your elegant solution. There is no grammar mistake and the application can be compliled and run. When `self.preview.cplot` was executed, error occured. 

`AttributeError: '_tkinter.tkapp' object has no attribute 'cplot'`

And another weird thing about tkinter. When i used code `EMDFrame(root,self.preview)` to creat the emdpage instance, I had to creat the preview instance before initiating the emdpage instance, which was understandable. Then the emdpage seemed to be part of the preview instance. In the GUI, emdpage instance was moved directly into the preview instance.

Comment: Thanks for your tips. Now i know the difference between class and intance. The question has been updated .